# Packer vpshere-iso stuck on wainting for Ip

Tags: linux, rhel, packer, vsphere

I am attempting to build a packer template using the following configuration for my packer JSON config file. However, I get packer stuck on waiting for an IP... and it doesn't make any progress.
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
    {
  "builders": [
    {
      "CPUs": 1,
      "RAM": 1024,
      "RAM_reserve_all": false,
      "boot_command": [
        "<esc><wait>",
        "linux ks=hd:fd0:packer/http/ks.cfg<enter>"
      ],
      "cluster": "{{user `vsphere-cluster`}}",
      "convert_to_template": true,
      "datacenter": "{{user `vsphere-datacenter`}}",
      "datastore": "{{user `vsphere-datastore`}}",
      "disk_controller_type": "pvscsi",
      "floppy_files": [
        "packer/http/ks.cfg"
      ],
      "folder": "{{user `folder`}}",
      "guest_os_type": "rhel7_64Guest",
      "insecure_connection": "true",
      "iso_paths": [
        "{{user `iso_url`}}"
      ],
      "network_adapters": [
        {
          "network": "{{user `vsphere-network`}}",
          "network_card": "vmxnet3"
        }
      ],
      "notes": "Build via Packer",
      "password": "{{user `vsphere-password`}}",
      "ssh_password": "{{user `ssh_pass`}}",
      "ssh_username": "{{user `ssh_user`}}",
      "storage": [
        {
          "disk_size": 25000,
          "disk_thin_provisioned": true
        }
      ],
      "type": "vsphere-iso",
      "username": "{{user `vsphere-user`}}",
      "vcenter_server": "{{user `vsphere-server`}}",
      "vm_name": "{{user `vm_name`}}"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "execute_command": "sudo {{.Vars}} sh {{.Path}}",
      "scripts": [
        "packer/scripts/cleanup.sh"
      ],
      "type": "shell"
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "folder": "Templates",
    "iso_url": "[datastore001] path/toiso/rhel-server-7.9-x86_64-dvd.iso",
    "ssh_pass": "password",
    "ssh_user": "root",
    "vm-cpu-num": "1",
    "vm-disk-size": "25600",
    "vm-mem-size": "1024",
    "vm_name": "packer-template-test",
    "vsphere-cluster": "cluster",
    "vsphere-datacenter": "datacenter",
    "vsphere-datastore": "datastore",
    "vsphere-network": "vsphere-network",
    "vsphere-password": "password2",
    "vsphere-server": "x.x.x.x",
    "vsphere-user": "admin"
  }
}
```

My Kickstart file looks like the following...

```
lang en_US
keyboard us
timezone America/New_York --isUtc
rootpw --iscrypted (*&YTHGRFDER^&VGGUYIUYIUY*&^&^&^UIYIYI

#Network
network --bootproto=static --ip=10.0.023 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --gateway=10.0.0.1 --nameserver=10.0.0.25 --device=ens192
#platform x86_64
reboot
text
nfs --server=x.x.x.x --dir=/path/to/iso/rhel-server-7.9-x86_64-dvd.iso
bootloader --location=mbr --append="rhgb quiet crashkernel=auto"
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
volgroup System --pesize=4000 pv.0 
part pv.0 --fstype=lvmpv --ondisk=sda --size=120000
part /boot --fstype=xfs --ondisk=sda2 --size=500
part /boot/efi --fstype=vfat --ondisk=sda1 --size=500
logvol swap --vgname=System --name=swap --fstype=swap --size=4000
logvol /home --vgname=System --name=home --fstype=xfs --size=500
logvol / --vgname=System --name=root --fstype=xfs --size=44000
auth --passalgo=sha512 --useshadow
selinux --disabled
firewall --enabled
firstboot --disable
%packages
@^graphical-server-environment
%end
```

This is my packer output after it times out after 30 minutes 23 seconds.
vsphere-iso: output will be in this color.

```
==> vsphere-iso: Creating VM...
==> vsphere-iso: Customizing hardware...
==> vsphere-iso: Mounting ISO images...
==> vsphere-iso: Adding configuration parameters...
==> vsphere-iso: Creating floppy disk...
    vsphere-iso: Copying files flatly from floppy_files
    vsphere-iso: Copying file: packer/http/ks.cfg
    vsphere-iso: Done copying files from floppy_files
    vsphere-iso: Collecting paths from floppy_dirs
    vsphere-iso: Resulting paths from floppy_dirs : []
    vsphere-iso: Done copying paths from floppy_dirs
    vsphere-iso: Copying files from floppy_content
    vsphere-iso: Done copying files from floppy_content
==> vsphere-iso: Uploading created floppy image
==> vsphere-iso: Adding generated Floppy...
==> vsphere-iso: Set boot order temporary...
==> vsphere-iso: Power on VM...
==> vsphere-iso: Waiting 10s for boot...
==> vsphere-iso: Typing boot command...
==> vsphere-iso: Waiting for IP...
==> vsphere-iso: Timeout waiting for IP.
==> vsphere-iso: Clear boot order...
==> vsphere-iso: Power off VM...
==> vsphere-iso: Deleting Floppy image ...
==> vsphere-iso: Destroying VM...
Build 'vsphere-iso' errored after 30 minutes 23 seconds: Timeout waiting for IP.

==> Wait completed after 30 minutes 23 seconds

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> vsphere-iso: Timeout waiting for IP.

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Comment: You need to install vmware-tools